# Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to make a login portal by referencing this tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

but as I wish to use Microsoft SQL Server instead of MySQL, I made some changes:

spring-database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=test" />

        <!-- <property name="username" value="root" /> <property name="password" 
            value="password" /> -->

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Then I got this problem when I was trying to run a project:

> 17:20:47,680 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 132) Context initialization failed:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while
>   setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
>   while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0':
>   FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0'
>   while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean
>   property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]: Error setting property
>   values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

Then I think I should focus on this:

> org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

The thing is that I included the JDB Cdriver in my project, but why this error shown?

The screenshot of the included driver
[image]

I am using wildfly 14.0.1 as server.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? The stack trace you posted is missing the original error that prevented the driver from loading. You should write a small test program that simply does a `Class.forName()` then you can see the real exception

Comment: I am using Java SE 10

Comment: I wrote a test program, then the result is the class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver is found.

Comment: Have you tried with sqljdbc4.2 not with ms-sql jar?

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency

Comment: The MS JDBC drivers only work for exactly the Java version they are intended for. So `.jre8.jar` only works with Java 8. You can download the versions for Java 10 and Java 11 from github: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases

Comment: mallikarjun: tried, same error shown

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: I change the pom.xml to this way<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>, then this error shown: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: haha being silly, should be <version>7.0.0.jre10</version>, but the same error keep showing even I changed

Comment: Have you actually deployed the driver in the WEB-INF/lib of your application (or deployed it as a module on Wildfly)?

Comment: mark rotteveel: I tried to add it into wildfly by referencing this link: https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/adding-sql-servers-jdbc-driver-into-wildfly/ But still showing error: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

Comment: i checked the log when the program was starting, there are logs that indicates the driver was loaded. [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 6.4)
[org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = sqlserver